# Should I capitalize the abbreviation for a unit of measurement?

Tags: capitalization, abbreviations, measuring-units

I'm creating a table in which everything in the columns are being treated like titles- "Suggested Serving Size," "Flavor of Yogurt," etc.

So how do I deal with this one- "Profit per 16 oz. Container"? Should it be "Profit per 16 Oz. Container?" I know ounce would be capitalized, but what's the protocol for abbreviations?

Comment: Why would you capitalize *ounce*?

Comment: @Mazura Because everything is title-case, and _ounce_ is a noun.

Comment: Oh. This is a (POB) manual of style question then.  *Should abbreviations of standardized units be capitalized when using title case?*

Answer (score 2):

If you start capitalizing common units, you risk mangling them into something else entirely.  It's not obvious what you would want a kelvin-gram (Kg) for, but a kilogram (kg) is a useful unit.  Similarly, a megalitre (Ml) is a large amount of something, but a millilitre (ml) is only a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Abbreviations for standardized units **are to appear exactly as they are shown** on Wiki's pages for them. Otherwise you're not using standardized (!) units.

[International System of Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)

[Imperial units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units)

[United States customary units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units)

Answer (score 1):

When abbreviating the name of a unit of measurement, stick to standard spellings, including standard capitalisation of those abbreviations.

Rationale: The field of units for measurement is so crowded, and the distinctions so important, that we need to jealously maintain even the distinctions granted by upper- and lower-case in order to tell the difference between units.

There is an important difference between 45 [nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanometre) and 10 [Nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_metre), for example, which should be preserved even when abbreviating the words. So play it safe and never change the case on any unit even when abbreviated.